# React useReducer hook TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jsx

action.type is throwing Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

```
function songReducer(state,action){
 switch (action.type){
     case "PLAY_SONG": {
         return {
             ...state,
             isPlaying: true
         }
     }
     default : return state;
 }
}
```

dispach is :

```
function handleTogglePlay(){
       dispatch({type:"PLAY_SONG"});

   }
```

Any clue on why : Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Comment: Did you define the `dispatch` and `state` as `const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(songReducer, initialState)`?

Comment: yes I did add  `const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(songReducer, initialState)`

Comment: I am not sure how you are using `useReducer` and `handleTogglePlay`. useReducer should be used within functional component and I cannot understand how `handleTogglePlay` function was used inside functional component. Can you share more details?

Comment: did you ever call dispatch() without arguments?